# How to install an AIR app from within a Flash Projector?

Tags: air, installation, flash

I have two files:

1. A company demonstration file, created with CS5, flash projector file: demo.exe
2. A catalog application, created with Flash Builder 4.6, air file: catalog.air

The distribution media is going to be CDROM. demo.exe file will, eventually, be setup as autorun file.

I need to be able to install the air app if not previously installed, or run it directly if already installed from within the "demo.exe" file.

**What I tried:**

1. Downloaded air.swf for checking installed air application,
2. Exported demo.exe as "access local files only"

**The Problem:**

air.swf returns null for the installed version of catalog.air, so that I can't figure out if catalog.air is installed or not.

**The Overcome:**

change "access local files only" to "acccess network only" and load air.swf from "http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf" then it will detect the installed version correctly.

**But then:**

Switching to "access network only" mode will prevent accessing the local catalog.air file. Hence, I can't get access to catalog.air and can't install it.

I am running out of my deadline and pulling my hair. Any hint pointing to right direction is mostly appreciated.

---

Update: Both flash and air app is using AS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AS1/2, try use `fscommand ("exec", filename)`, it may ignore "access network only" restriction.

`fscommand ("exec", "catalog.air")`

or

`fscommand ("exec", "installMyApp.bat")` (`installMyApp.bat` runs `catalog.air`)

`catalog.air/installMyApp.bat` must be in `fscommand` dir near your `demo.exe`

Comment: sorry for not explicitly indicating the version of AS i am using, it is AS3 :(